# Filter django view with or condition

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

If I want to limit an object in Django within my view to show a filtered list based on if a user is added or if the user is an author, how can I create that condition?

I attempted to filter with an or statement but this just displayed duplicates.

```
return Group.objects.filter(author=user or users__in=[user])
```

What would be the proper way to format or create this logic?

Comment: Have you used the `distinct()` method to omit the dups?

Comment: I didn't but I am pretty new with django. I appreciate this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Q` objects, and make use of the bitwise or operator (`|`) to represent a disjunction between the two conditions:

```
from django.db.models import Q

return Group.objects.filter(Q(author=user) | Q(users=user))
```

If the `author` matches together with one (or more) of the `users`, then the same `Group` will be returned multiple times. You can make use of [**`.distinct()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve such `Group` only once:

```
from django.db.models import Q

return Group.objects.filter(Q(author=user) | Q(users=user)).distinct()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.